# Regular expression for URI that ends in a number

Tags: regex

Can you please suggest regular expression for my URL. I am trying to parse a URL that is supposed to have only digits after the last trailing slash:

```
http://localhost/myproj/myservice/api/v4/lists/45678333
```

When I try this regular expression:

```
(http|https)://([A-z0-9|\.|\-]*)/myproj/myservice/api/v([.\d{1}])/lists/(.\d+$)
```

It is also accepting `a45678333` as the last number. I just wanted to be a number of any length.

How do I form the regular expression that matches the number (and only a number) after the last slash?

Comment: You want the number at the end? That is just `(\d+)$`

Answer (score 1):

`/(.\d+$)` matches a `/`, then any single character followed by any number of digits at the end.

To match only digits at the end, you need:

```
/\d+$
```

If you want to capture the digits in a group:

```
/(\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/bT3fZ0/1), it will help you out:

```
(http|https):\/\/([A-z0-9|.|-]*)\/myproj\/myservice\/api\/v(‌​[.\d{1}])\/lists\/(​\d+$)
```

Comment: (http|https):\/\/([A-z0-9|.|-]*)\/myproj\/myservice\/api\/v([.\d{1}])\/lists\/(.\d+$)

i have added this in that link , that would be helpful to look into

Comment: From @heemayl's analysis, th problem is with the leading dot in `/(.\d+$)`. How does this answer avoid matching any character and then a digit string?